# Best way to update entity collection field in API

Tags: java, rest

I have an entity called Teacher in my database, and this entity has a Many-to-Many relationship with the Discipline entity. It also has other relationships. And I am trying to design a CRUD web API for a service that handles teachers, in a RESTful way, of course.

I faced the problem that a simple implementation of PUT or PATCH method would be insufficient and just weird when it used for updating `disciplines` collection field. I mean, if I simply want to add one discipline, I would, using PATCH, need to pass the full collection, including the new one, and on the back-end side check, which is the new one, and add it. I understand that I can define an endpoint like `.../tearchers/{teacher_id}/addDiscipline` with PATCH method or similar to remove, but as REST says, it is better to avoid verbs in API...

So I am looking for advices/best practices on how to design Update operation for entity collection field in API in a RESTful way.

Comment: I'd be inclined to POST to an endpoint like: `/teacher/{teacherId}/discipline` - with the body containing the necessary attributes (and the URL providing the relationship back to the teacher) - side note, I also prefer to use singular for URLs (i.e. `/teacher` instead of `/teachers` - dunno if it's a best practice but I've seen it more often than not)

Comment: @blurfus make sense, thanks for your opinion,
maybe duplicate your comment in answers section? so others would see that question has some answers

Answer (score 0):

I would do this way:

If you want to add an existing discipline to a teacher then create a POST endpoint like "/teachers/{teacherId}/disciplines/{disciplineId}".

Otherwise if you want to create and link a discipline to a teacher then create a POST endpoint like "/teachers/{teacherId}/disciplines" with a body containing all the necessary data.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to `POST` to an endpoint like: `/teacher/{teacherId}/discipline`

with the body containing the necessary attributes (and the URL providing the relationship back to the teacher)

Side note, I also prefer to use singular for URLs (i.e. `/teacher` instead of `/teachers` - dunno if it's a best practice but I've seen it more often than not)